# How do I use a SP in SQL Server 2014 to call a external XML source?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am attempting to retrieve Currency Exchange rates from http://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.xml using a SP in SQL Server 2014. The result is in XML. So I created the following SProc:

```
--DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_CallWebService]
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_CallWebService]
AS
    DECLARE @obj INT
    DECLARE @sURL VARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @response varchar(max)

    SET @sURL = 'http://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.xml'

    EXEC sys.sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
    EXEC sys.sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @sURL, FALSE
    EXEC sys.sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send'
    EXEC sys.sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @response OUT

    SELECT @response [response]
    EXEC sys.sp_OADestroy @obj
RETURN
```

and when I run the SProc I get `NULL` in return instead of the XML.

What do I need to change in my Proc to get an XML response from that site mentioned above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK Fully tested the following SP which pulls back your XML Data:

```
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_CallWebService]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_CallWebService]
AS
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xml') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #xml
    CREATE TABLE #xml ( Data xml )

    DECLARE @obj INT
    DECLARE @sURL VARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @response varchar(max)

    SET @sURL = 'http://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.xml'

    DECLARE @XML xml
    DECLARE @Result int 
    DECLARE @HTTPStatus int 
    DECLARE @ErrorMsg varchar(MAX)

    EXEC @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHttp', @Obj OUT 
    EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @sURL, false
    EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'text/html'
    EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, send, NULL, ''
    EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'status', @HTTPStatus OUT 
    --EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml', --@Response OUT


    INSERT #xml ( Data )
   EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml'--, @Response OUT 
    SELECT * from #xml
RETURN
```

The way i got around it, was to use the #xml hash temp table to retrieve the response, and to select the response into it.

This is because of the way that MIME types and the downloading of the file contents is actually completed, originally it was only bringing back a binary value, with no response header, and that was because it wasnt actually completeting the full action of doing the conversion to the XML

-- For anyone that needs the below, im keeping it as part of this comment

When i try and run your SP i get the following Error: 
But it does return me back a response of NULL.

```
Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_OACreate, Line 1
SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.sp_OACreate' of component 'Ole Automation Procedures' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ole Automation Procedures' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ole Automation Procedures', search for 'Ole Automation Procedures' in SQL Server Books Online.
```

To Fix this issue,

Right click on your 
Server Instance -> then click Facets
Then select "Server Configuration" under Facets
and in the Facet Properties change OleAutomationEnabled = true

OR if that doesnt work use this in a Query Window inside SQL Server Management Tools.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

The documentation for the above statement is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms191188.aspx

Comment: @JohnSchultz ive updated that answer to now bring back your XML succesfully.

Answer (score -1):

I think your best bet would be to create a .Net stored proc to do this instead of trying to use the sp_OACreate. That technique is legacy and much more unstable. .Net procedures are an amazing way to add functionality like this to SQL Server, but they are much overlooked.